# When you perform a copyField in Solr, does the field boost go with it?

Tags: solr

Say I have these field declarations:

```
<field name="Title" type="text_general" stored="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="Body" type="text_general" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

When I index "Title," I set the boost to 5, meaning words in the "Title" field should count for 5x normal.

Then I do this:

```
<copyField source="Title" dest="SearchText"/>
<copyField source="Body" dest="SearchText"/>
```

So, I have copied both fields into another field called "SearchText."

When I search "SearchText," are terms from the "Title" field still carrying their 5x boost?  Or do they lose that in the copy?  When you do a copyField, does the boost of all fields get "leveled out"?

Answer (score 11):

After doing some reading, I think the boost gets stripped.  Our solution was do to this:

We created four fields: SearchText, SearchText2, SearchText3, and SearchText4.  We copy *everything* into SearchText, some stuff into SearchText2, less stuff into SearchText3, and only the super-critical stuff into SearchText4.

Then, our "qf" param looks like this:

```
SearchText, SearchText2^3, SearchText3^10, SearchText4^100
```

So, we're boosting the fields by none, 3, 10, and 100 at query time.

It doesn't look graceful, but it works well and it allows us to adjust boost without reindexing.

Also, there's an abstraction layer here: by putting something in SearchText2, for instance, we're saying "This is important," however, we're not defining *how* important (in terms of numeric boost) until query time.  So, the copyField is the abstraction, and the "qf" param in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the boost is on a field per basis. So, if you have applied a boost to the "Title" field, then the "SearchText" field does not have the same boost. You will have to give a separate boost to the "SearchText" field in order to boost the matches.

Comment: There are both document and field boosts. So Im not too sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `copyfield`, the field's boost is not copied with it.  However, there is a simple solution that does not require changing your queries.

If you do multiple `copyfield`'s for the same field, it will be copied multiple times into the result, thus boosting it's weight.

So, for you to achieve 5x weight on the title, you could simply do the `copyfield` five times.

```
<copyField source="Title" dest="SearchText"/>
<copyField source="Title" dest="SearchText"/>
<copyField source="Title" dest="SearchText"/>
<copyField source="Title" dest="SearchText"/>
<copyField source="Title" dest="SearchText"/>
<copyField source="Body" dest="SearchText"/>
```